# Custom GridLayout

Tags: android, grid-layout, android-gridlayout, gridlayoutmanager

I'm trying to make some auto fill grid, but without know the width from every item. So, the width from child can be deferent in every row and every column. It only depends from a TextView.

I want something like this.

[image: I Want this]

I'm tried with GridLayout and `android:numColumns="auto_fit"` but isn't what I'm looking for.
I also check [this post](http://blog.sqisland.com/2014/12/recyclerview-autofit-grid.html) but is basically same as GridLayout.
Anyone know some other solutions??

Comment: I think you are looking for "FlowLayout" in Android

Answer (score 3):

**Flexbox-Layout** is a project by Google to provide both a simple view and a `RecyclerView` layout manager that does what you want. https://github.com/google/flexbox-layout

Comment: Thanks @Ben P. Finally I used Flexbox-Layout .

Answer (score 0):

> I think the following tutorial might be a solution for the current problem u r facing
>   [Tutorial](https://www.androidhive.info/2016/05/android-working-with-card-view-and-recycler-view/)

Hope it helps ;)